# Issue with the property "autoSubscribeNewMembers" and the actual behaviour

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have been able to confirm that the `autoSubscribeNewMembers` property is `false` on my Office Group, using this kind of query against Graph API:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/3eb24624-3c3d-4bce-ad93-6a00aa73812f/?$select=autoSubscribeNewMembers
```

Nevertheless, when I add a new member to the Group, he receives email notifications whenever a new message is posted on the Group. Users did not subscribed manually to the notifications since they do not have access to OWA.

Does anyone have the same behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the user has subscribed the group mail. You can call https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_unsubscribebymail to unsubscribe the group.

Comment: I doubt it's possible. As I said in the topic, end-users do not have access to OWA and cannot subscribe to the Group notifications.